# Displaying an element on top of all frames

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jquery menu which is displayed when user clicks a link. The problem is, no matter what I try, part of the menu gets cut off when it doesn't fit into original frame. Is it possible at all to do it?

Below is a screenshot to better illustrate my issue:

[image: cut off menu]

z-index option doesn't have any effect on frame tags.

Please don't suggest to move away from frames, this is and old app (10+ years), and I can't change it.

Thanks,
Roman

Comment: No, that is not possible. Frames are independent window instances, and you can not make content go out of the “normal” window in a page without frames either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't overflow outside of the frame you're limited to. One approach to this is trying to adjust the menus to detect if the submenu will overflow the page, to anchor the bottom of the menu instead of the top. Much like the context menu if you try to right click close to the bottom of a web page.

Answer (score 1):

Not without modifying things.  Two suggestions that spring to mind:

1. Make the menus aware of the size they've got to display themselves and modify their position to fit / use multiple columns, or
2. Set the background of your frame to transparent and grow the height of the frame to fit the menu after each menu opens.

I've personally used the second approach before, however the caveat is that the frame sits on top of content underneath.  Users are unable to click on content they can see through the transparent frame.

Comment: No worries, my suggestion 1 is pretty much exactly what you decided to go with, it looks like.  :-)